# GameCenter getting same view for all players

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, game-center

I am using game center in my app, and managing with the GKTurnbasedMatch game.

I have a view in which i have to select the category based on which i will get cards in my next view ,
then in next view i have invites view of gamecenter.

The thing that i want is that the card and category for all the player for the same match should be similar,so that if card1 flips in 1 player then all the players card 1 should flip.

How to get this?

Comment: Post a notification, and observe it. Whenever you receive it, do whatever you want to.

Comment: will the notification work for all player and will it give me the view of host view to all players view?